# Cant create, delete or rename files

Tags: samba

**/etc/passwd**

```
[..]
seagate:x:1000:1001:,,,:/mnt/seagate/:/bin/false
medion:x:1002:1003:,,,:/mnt/medion:/bin/false
seagate_ro:x:1001:1002:,,,:/mnt/seagate:/bin/false
wwwusr:x:1003:1005:,,,:/var/www:/bin/false
```

**/etc/group**

```
[..]
www-data:x:33:www-usr
seagate:x:1001:
medion:x:1003:
seagate_ro:x:1002:
wwwusr:x:1005:
```

**pdbedit -L**

```
[..]
wwwusr:1003:
medion:1002:
seagate:1000:
seagate_ro:1001:
```

**/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
[global]
        netbios aliases = refly1 refly2 refly3 refly4 refly5
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        server string = %h server (Samba %v)
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        encrypt passwords = true
        invalid users = root
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY
        security = user
        unix extensions = yes

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        browseable = no
        valid users = %S
        writable = no
        write list = seagate medion wwwusr
        create mode = 0600
        directory mode = 0700
```

**testparm**

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[homes]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions
```

**In windows explorer**

```
M: \\refly2\medion
S: \\refly3\seagate
W: \\refly1\wwwusr
```

**ls -ld /var/www**

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 777 www-data 4096 Mai  9 13:29 /var/www
```

**Problem:**
Can not create, delete or rename files with `wwwusr`. If I use `seagate`, `seagate_ro (ro = read only)` or `medion` to access their home directories they do their job perfectly. So where is the problem?

To setup my samba I used [this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198545/mount-linux-mount-in-windows-without-ftp/198546#198546).

Comment: What are actually the permissions set on `/var/www` ?

Comment: I don't know. How to proof that? I deleted the whole folder and recreated it a couple of hours ago.

Comment: Run `ls -ld /var/www` and provide result

Comment: Added to main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see using :

```
ls -ld /var/www
drwxr-xr-x 2 777 www-data 4096 Mai  9 13:29 /var/www
```

The `/var/www` folder is owned by user `777` (?) which have `rwx` permissions as it is the owner.

Then, `www-data` group has `rx` permission.

Finally, all others users, including your `wwwusr` user has rx permissions.

**Alternative 1**

If you have a website setup and running in `/var/www` i would do the following to not break things on your working website :

1. Add user `wwwusr` to the additional group `www-data` :

   ```
   usermod -G www-data wwwusr
   ```
2. Then give write permissions to group `www-data` on the folder :

   ```
   chmod g+w /var/www
   ```

**Alternative 2**

If this don't break the website you may be running (test it), just make user `wwwusr` the owner of the folder :

```
chown wwwusr:wwwusr /var/www
```

---

**Edit about permission :**

In your Samba config you use :

```
create mode = 0600
```

This tells Samba that each new created files will have `rw` permissions only for the owner :

```
-rw------- 1 wwwusr wwwusr 65 Mai 9 15:08 /var/www/index.html
```

You may change it to :

```
create mode = 0605
```

This will add `rx` permissions to other users.

The above also applies to this directive you use :

```
directory mode = 0700
```

It will give `rwx` permission to owner only on each newly created folders. No permissions to group nor others.

Use `directory mode = 0705` to add `rx` permissions to others on folders.

==> Warning : all these will also affect permissions for others users home directories content the same way. As discussed, it is not a problem for you.

---

- All these is documented in the [Samba config guide](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html).
- You may also find interesting this [online permission calculator](http://permissions-calculator.org/).

Comment: Aww that simple? Thank you, that fixed it!
I'm new to linux and I think I'm right here!

Comment: Now I'm getting another error: `404 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server`. The index.html has been created by notepad.exe over `\\refly1\wwusr`.

Comment: Please see my edit regarding alternatives. What is the result for `ls -l /var/www/index.html` ?

Comment: `-rw------- 1 wwwusr wwwusr 65 Mai  9 15:08 /var/www/index.html`. The files has been created by `wwwusr`. A `index.html`, created by `nano index.html` is perfectly working. If i edit this file by notepad++ it's still working.

Comment: Try this : `chmod o+rx /var/www/index.html`

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. So how to give all files this permission automatically?

Comment: I've edited my answer to cover this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23607/discussion-between-8m47x-and-krisfr).

Comment: Thank you so much again for that :) Where is all that knowledge documented?

Comment: This is documented in the [Samba config guide](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html). Also you may find this interesting to "calculate" permissions : http://permissions-calculator.org/